# Torch boolean indexing along both dimensions

Tags: python, pytorch

Let's say you have a 2D-square Tensor:

```py
x = torch.tensor([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
                  [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
                  [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
                  [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
                  [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
                  [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]])
```

And you want to select the sub-tensor with rows and columns of index 0, 2, 3 considering you have a tensor `keep` such as:

```py
keep = torch.tensor([True, False, True, True, False, False])
```

The desired output is then:

```py
tensor([[ 0,  2,  3],
        [12, 14, 15],
        [18, 20, 21]])
```

### Something that does not work

I expected `x[keep, keep]` to work but it only selects elements on the diagonal.

### Making it work the long way - Masks

One way is to use a mask but it is quite tedious:

```py
mask = keep.view(-1, 1) * keep
submatrix_size = keep.sum()
x[mask].view(sub_matrix_size, -1)
```

### Making it work the short way

Another way to do it is:

```py
x[keep][:, keep]
```

My question is then: Is the short way the best way to select on both dimensions with the same boolean tensor ? Is there any other way to do it in PyTorch?